# JQuery Sortable : Making sortable elements non-draggable, yet sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Consider the following **HTML**

```
<div class="sortcontainer">
    <div class="item">  i1</div>
    <div class="item">  i2</div>
    <div class="item nondraggable">  i3</div>
    <div class="item">   i4</div>
    <div class="item">  i5</div>
    <div class="item nondraggable">  i6</div>
    <div class="item nondraggable">  i7</div>
    <div class="item">  i8</div>
</div>
```

I am applying a `sortable` (jQuery UI) on the `sortcontainer` `div`.

**I want to make some items (here `i3`, `i6` and `i7`) non-draggable. But they should remain sortable in the list**.

I tried disabling sorting for those items. If I do that, they will become non-draggable, but their position will be freezed. For example, once I disable them, i wont be able to drop anything between `i6` and `i7` as they are disabled.

I want to be able to make these elements non-draggable yet remain sortable.

Any ideas?

**JSFiddle Link** : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/neekdamon/pSe9c/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `cancel` parameter to set elements that should not be dragged.

```
cancel: '.nondraggable',
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/pSe9c/1/

Comment: Thanks!! That was easier than I thought. May be next time I should read the API more thoroughly!